# how to calculate precision for my question answering answers

Tags: precision, precision-recall

Could you please tell me a way to calculate precision  , Recall , accuracy and F1 for my system having the attached table?

[how to calculate the attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDNDy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Precision =number of correct answers /number of questions answered 
Recall =number of correct answers /number of questions to be answered 
F measure =2* (Precision * recall) /Precision +recall
```

I figured out the answer